# How to block app silent installation

Tags: google-play-store, adb, security, installation, apk

Recently I noticed I have opera browser installed. I definitely did not install it because I was sleeping at that time. I checked installation time and revealed it was the day before yesterday

[image]

Checking installation source like this outputs `android`:

```
adb shell dumpsys package com.opera.browser | grep -e "installerPackageName"
```

so I don't know whether it was through Play Store or through APK.

Can I found out who have done this and how can I prevent future intrusions?

P.S. I have MIUI 11.0.3 Global device

**UPDATE:**

**INSTALL_PACKAGES** permission

apps

- com.miui.msa.global
- com.android.vending
- com.miui.cloudbackup
- com.google.android.packageinstaller
- com.xiaomi.mipicks
- com.android.managedprovisioning
- com.facebook.system
- com.miui.analytics
- com.xiaomi.discover

users

- android.uid.backup
- android.uid.shell

services

- com.lbe.security.miui/com.lbe.security.service.SecurityService

**REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES** permission

- android
- com.miui.msa.global
- com.android.browser
- com.miui.player
- com.google.android.gm
- com.google.android.apps.docs
- com.android.chrome
- com.xiaomi.midrop
- com.miui.hybrid
- com.miui.securityadd

users

- android.uid.bluetooth

Comment: AFAIK playstore always sets the installer, so I rather suspect a different source. I'd copy `adb logcat` ASAP (might be too late for this case, as the buffer is certainly already overwritten after two days) and `grep` that for evidence. For potential culprits, check which apps have the permission to install other apps (`INSTALL_PACKAGES`) – though AFAIK only system apps should be granted that. Logcat still is the best approach, if you catch such an issue in time.

Comment: `check which apps have the permission to install other apps (INSTALL_PACKAGES)` how to do this system-wide? or the only way is one-by-one approach?

Comment: `adb shell dumpsys package | grep INSTALL_PACKAGES` would come to mind. Or just taking the output of `dumpsys package` and use some editor/viewer to look for that string (might be easier to get the context that way). Of course you could also "automate" that by something like `for app in $(adb shell pm list packages |awk -F: '{print $NF}'); do adb shell dumpsys package $app | grep INSTALL_PACKAGES; done`, which then should give you a list of package+perm.

Comment: unfortunately logcat was overwritten already. Is there any way to increase logcat persistence period?

Comment: @Izzy added apps with permissions in question update, anything looks suspicious to you? should be facebook able to install?

Comment: look [at this](https://imgur.com/a/vzJCCzv). Can Facebook App Manager install anything or only his own apps?

Comment: Might be possible. But please forgive that I cannot analyze your apps for you – especially not those I don't use myself (or even have on my devices). My hints were intended to get you started, I cannot dig deeper into that myself.

Comment: but what is the correct way of analysis? can you give hints or some docs?

Comment: Sorry, I currently lack the time to dig into that. There are some apps capable of "collecting" the logcat, keeping a "full copy" e.g. on the SD card for later investigation (see [here](https://android.izzysoft.de/catmin/applists/category/named/tools_logcat) and watch e.g. for "Syslog") – so once you notice such an app popping up, you can grep that collection for details; installation should appear there, too. That's the approach I'd try.